# Customizar um item dentro do css para uma determinada view

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Eu tenho essa view no MVC

**View**

```
@model XXX
@{

}

<link href="/eTeste/Content/AbaDetailsODM.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="consoleAbaDetalhes"></div>

<div id="campos_detail">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        "xxxx",
        "xxxx",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "consoleAba",
            HttpMethod = "POST",

        }))
    {
        @Html.Partial("Validation")
        @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.IdEmpresa)
        @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.IdModeloVersao)
        [...]

        <div id="campos">
            <div class="CampoRealyOnly">
                @Html.EditorFor(i => i.User)
                <div class="clear"></div>
                @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Gerente)
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div id="chefesDeProjeto">
                @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Descricao, "TextArea", new { colunas = 30, linhas = 5 })
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="CampoRealyOnly clear field-middle">

            <h3>@Html.Label(ODMResources.AreaLeader):</h3>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ResponsaveisFuncao)
            </div>
            [...] //Vários Campos
        </div>
```

O sistema tem seu próprio CSS dos campos.
Eu gostaria de alterar uma parte desse CSS, só para esta View.
Essa parte é generica do sistema.

O css funciona como eu gostaria, o problema é que ele altera todas as outras abas, mesmo tendo referenciado ele apenas nessa view.
Acredito que seja o modo cascata que faz com que seja alterado em tudo.

O que eu poderia fazer pra separar isso, sendo algo generico do sistema?

**CSS**

```
.CampoRealyOnly
input[type=text], textarea, select
{
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    left: 298px;
    position: relative;
    top: -29px;
}
h3
{
    color: Red;
}
```

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi. Você tem uma view que contém x campos que você quer que sejam visualmente diferentes dos campos fora dela (no _layout) por exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive que criar seletores para a propria classe.
No final ficou assim:

```
.CampoRealyOnly input[type=text], .CampoRealyOnly textarea, .CampoRealyOnly select
{
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    left: 298px;
    position: relative;
    top: -29px;
}
```

Comment: Neste acaso acredito que a resposta do @DanielGroh é a correta, pois ele te deu essa dica. De qualquer forma não esqueça de aceita uma resposta para a sua pergunta.

Comment: Desculpa, mas antes vi em outro lugar!

Comment: Então aceite a sua resposta como a correta

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que usar sua própria classe, de preferência extendendo os selectores genéricos, no seu caso `input[type=text], textarea, select` etc...

Se você gostaria de mudar o estilo de uma aba específica, crie uma classe específica para esta aba, assim você sabe do que se trata, por exemplo:

```
input[type=text].nomeAba{
  seu estilo aqui
}
```

agora basta envolver sua aba dentro da classe `nomeAba`, pode ser uma `div`

Repare que mencionei a palavra "específico", o que acaba entrando neste assunto: [Specifics On Css Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) onde você encontrará referencias que te ajudem.